# What are the good machine learning and data minning libraries for Ruby or is there any?

Tags: ruby, frameworks, machine-learning

I plan to do some ML programming on Ruby on Rails project and I am searching for any ML framework on Ruby. I searched on Google of course but cannot find any satisfying one so I decide to consult to crowd's wisdom.

Answer (score 1):

I would not say there are any 'good' library for machine learning written in pure ruby since machine learning is fairly computationally expensive. A good library will likely wrap a c interface to a well known library. So you could try and find a good c library and create a ruby wrapper of the library.

An alternative would be to use JRuby and import a java based library. Here is an article about importing weka.

http://rubyforscientificresearch.blogspot.ca/2009/08/accessing-weka-from-jruby.html

There may be application specific libraries for what you are doing using machine learning? If you are trying to do recommendations try the [recommendify](https://github.com/paulasmuth/recommendify) gem.

Another alternative is to use a webservice. There is the google prediction api which has a [ruby client](http://code.google.com/p/ruby-google-prediction-api/).